# unattended upgrades - which shutdown command works?

Tags: unattended-upgrades

i have unattended upgrades set to run on shutdown.

which of these commands will allow unattended upgrades to happen [and not skip them]

```
poweroff
systemctl poweroff
shutdown
reboot
```

Comment: Not a real answer but `halt`, `poweroff`, and `reboot` are legacy commands  that are available for backwards compatibility only and should not be used.

Comment: They're all running `systemctl` in the end (three of them are symlinks to systemctl and the fourth is systemctl itself)

Comment: Where have you set to run unattended upgrades on shutdown? That's quite risky.. if something fails and your system is rebooted unattended it might get lost...